# MS Access Autonumber Field Set Start Index

Tags: ms-access

Is there a way to set the start index of autonumber field in ms access?

It's start on `1` and i want it start at `1000`

Comment: I don't thinks so but you could always write a routine to create 999 records and then delete them again!

Comment: You shouldn't. The intent of an autonumber field is to uniquely identify records. If you want to use a functional autonumbering (like order number, product number, invoice number), you should define your own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manually add an ID column with a specific seed. This also can be used in `CREATE TABLE` statements. Note that, for existing records, the ID doesn't start at 1000 but at 1.

```
ALTER TABLE A Add Column ID AutoIncrement(1000,1) PRIMARY KEY
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `INSERT` SQL query to add one record with ID=999 and delete it. Next autonumber ID will be 1000